# Convincing proof of quotient rule using Landau's notation

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, derivatives

I'm taking a Complex Analysis course this semester which follows D. Ulrich's Complex Made Simple.

One of the earliest exercises in Chapter 0 is to re-derive the usual Calculus rules for differentiation of sums, products and quotients.

I can easily prove the quotient rule by a direct calculation of limits. However, for consistency with the book's exposition and my solution to the other exercises, I would like to prove it using Landau's notations.

Since I have already proven the product rule, it suffices to stablish that if $g$ is differentiable at $z$ and $g(z) \neq 0$, $(1/g)'(z) = - (g'/g^2)(z)$.

My attempt of a proof:

For small $h$, write

$$ \frac{1}{g(z+h)} - \frac{1}{g(z)} =  \frac{g(z) - g(z+h)}{g(z+h) g(z)} \text{.}$$

Since by hypothesis $g(z+h) = g(z) + g'(z) h + o(h)$ as $h \to 0$, one may write:

\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{g(z+h)} - \frac{1}{g(z)} &=  \frac{- g'(z)h + o(h)}{\left( g(z) + O(h) \right) g(z)} \; \text{ as $h \to 0$} \\ &= - \frac{g'(z)}{\left( g(z) + O(h) \right) g(z)} h + o(h) \; \text{ as $h \to 0$,}
\end{align*}

and now the result seems obvious. However, now I cannot get rid of this $O(h)$ in a satisfactory manner. Does it automatically disappears since $h \to 0$? How could I justify it from the definition?

Just to make it clear, the text says that $f$ is differentiable at $z$ iff $f(z+h) = f(z) + f'(z)h + o(h)$ as $h \to 0$, so in theory I'd need the exact expression for the derivative multiplying $h$ in the last expression above.

Comment: What it boils down to is showing that $ \frac{1}{g(z)+O(h)}-\frac{1}{g(z)} = O(h) $. You can probably do that by introducing explicit constants and using the binomial theorem.

Comment: It is not clear that for me that it boils down to that. I must produce a result about the derivative, this would give me at most continuity.

Comment: I mean going from the equation that you've got down to, which has a $-g'(z)/[(g(z)+O(h))g(z)]$, to the one that you want, which would have a $-g'(z)/[g(z)]^2$, with a difference of $O(h)$.